# __NSCFConstantString _beforeActivity for Custom Activity in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

I want to share image,link through own app as activity type is used subclass UIActivity class and used this action method code

```
  NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n",[self.dataModel artLook_Title]];
    UIImage *imageToShare =self.profileImageView.image; //[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.jpg"];
    if (self.tinyURL==nil) {
        [self initilizeTinyURL];
    }
     NSArray *items = @[message,[self tinyURL],imageToShare];//
    NSArray *activities = @[[self customActivity],UIActivityTypePostToFacebook,UIActivityTypePostToTwitter];
    UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:items applicationActivities:activities];
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I am crash at

```
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

> Error:-[__NSCFConstantString _beforeActivity]: unrecognized selector
>   sent to instance 0x38f2b6b8

Any help will appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
NSArray *activities = @[[self customActivity],UIActivityTypePostToFacebook,UIActivityTypePostToTwitter];
```

You are passing in your own custom activity (good) and two string constants for standard activities (bad).

1. You can't pass `NSString` where `UIActivity` is expected.
2. Why are you specifying standard activities in the array where you are only supposed to provide your app-specific activities?

Change the line to:

```
NSArray *activities = @[[self customActivity]];
```

If your goal is to only show certain activities, use the `excludedActivityTypes` property to list the standard activities you don't want. This is where you use the standard `UIActivityTypeXXX` constants.

Answer (score 1):

this line is error

```
 NSArray *activities = @[[self customActivity],UIActivityTypePostToFacebook,UIActivityTypePostToTwitter];
```

> -[__NSCFConstantString _beforeActivity]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x38f2b6b8 -- The error says you were passing the nil or String object in `applicationActivities`

the `UIActivity` expects a list of UIActivity objects